# How to authenticate user without auth:api middleware in laravel 5.3?

Tags: laravel, authentication, request, laravel-5.3

I have a public route that any user can access it. (`/timeline`).
In this action if user is authenticated, I must show him if he has liked the post.
If the route has `auth:api` middleware I can get authenticated user using `$request->user()`, but if I don't use `auth:api` middleware I can't check if user is authenticated even if user sends correct access_token.
How can I check if access_token is correct without middleware and authenticate user in controller?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can pass the guard to your method to check if the user is logged in with a particular guard.

```
$request->user('api');
```

**EDIT**

I just want to extend my original answer.

Using `$request->user()` is exactly the same as using `\Auth::user()`.

When you retrieve the authenticated user, Laravel will default the guard from your config file `auth.defaults.guard` (`web` in a fresh install).

So when you called `$request->user()` it was actually `$request->user('web')`.

When you use `auth:api`, Laravel will then use the `api` guard as the default.

That's why it worked when using `auth:api` but didn't when using default guard.

To solve your issue, you can either call `$request->user('api')` if you have an `Illuminate\Http\Request` instance or directly `\Auth::guard('api')->user()` using the `Auth` facade.

Comment: You can also use **Auth::guard('api')->user()** without a Request Object.

Comment: @Gkiokan, I assumed he already had the request object for other stuff since he was already using it. But your point is still good though.

Comment: Correct. Consider the fact when you won't have a Request object you can use the Guard to access the User Object. Just in case you don't want to use or whyever won't have a Request Object. :)

Comment: can you provide a whole check code to understand how the process work , and thank you

Comment: @ReemAziz what do you mean by « whole check code »?

Comment: @PeterPan666 I mean I want to check if the user authenticate in the requst body like ask the user to send the token with other parms , and i asked you to expline the process  to me with a sample code like  any create function

Comment: @ReemAziz Well, if you already have a request object you could do `$request->user('api') !== null` to check if the user is connected or you can do `Auth::guard('api')->check()`. Take a look at the Laravel doc on guards and authentication here https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication

Answer (score 5):

If you're using [Sanctum](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#introduction) instead of Passport:

`$request->user('sanctum');`

Answer (score 3):

You are using `auth:api` so I assume you are talking JSON request. Access token usually sits in the header of your request, so you can just check it like this

```
public function timeline(Request $request) {
    if ( $request->has('access_token') || $request->header('access_token') ) {
        $user = Auth::guard('api')->user();
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: This is more useful when you don't have the Request instance injected to your method. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the time to dig in the code, but you can look at the auth:api middleware. There you will find how the authentication process works. If you haven't found a thing let me know and I'll look into it tonight and improve my answer.

In the file `Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CheckClientCredentials` you will find this:

```
<?php

namespace Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use League\OAuth2\Server\ResourceServer;
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;
use League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\OAuthServerException;
use Symfony\Bridge\PsrHttpMessage\Factory\DiactorosFactory;

class CheckClientCredentials
{
    /**
     * The Resource Server instance.
     *
     * @var ResourceServer
     */
    private $server;

    /**
     * Create a new middleware instance.
     *
     * @param  ResourceServer  $server
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(ResourceServer $server)
    {
        $this->server = $server;
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$scopes)
    {
        $psr = (new DiactorosFactory)->createRequest($request);

        try{
            $psr = $this->server->validateAuthenticatedRequest($psr);
        } catch (OAuthServerException $e) {
            throw new AuthenticationException;
        }

        foreach ($scopes as $scope) {
           if (!in_array($scope,$psr->getAttribute('oauth_scopes'))) {
             throw new AuthenticationException;
           }
         }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

When you dig deeper you will see that the request gets validated here  `League\OAuth2\Server\RecourceServer.php`. My guess is that you will find your answer there