# How to have a route for both authenticated users and non-authenticated users

Tags: laravel, oauth, routes, middleware, laravel-passport

I have an issue with auth:api middleware!
We have a request that is accessible for both authenticated users and non-authenticated users when I define a route like this for non-authenticated users:

```
Route::post('{user}/leads', 'UsersController@getContact');
```

It's ok everything work fine when a guest user requesting this route.
is and I can access user with `$request->user();`

but if pass token with bearer header and get the user with `$request->user()` of course it doesn't work! because we didn't use `auth:api` on this route, and if we do we can't  access this route with guest users!
So I can't find a way that we define one route for both authenticated users that if user is authenticated we get `$request->user()` and none authenticated users can access that route too!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to create your own middleware for this type of customization.

Comment: I don't understand why `auth:api` would be required for the user to be available. The `auth:api` middleware only rejects requests to routes when a valid user token is not present.  It doesn't magically make the token available. Typically you'd do an `Auth::check()` to determine if there's a valid user accessing the route.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found a way to do that I just wrote this:

```
$middleware = ['api'];
if (\Request::header('Authorization')) 
   $middleware = array_merge(['auth:api']);
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1', 'namespace' => 'Api', 'middleware' => $middleware], function () {
    //routes here
});
```

In api.php route file and it works fine.
Thanks

Comment: Do you find another better way to do that?

Comment: great! worked for me, was looking for this solution for few hours!

Comment: @MohammadFanni No, but this is an old thread, maybe there are new features to do it in Laravel 10.x

Answer (score 4):

This is because `Auth` uses the default `web` guard. You have to check the `api` guard manually:

```
$user = Auth::user() ?? Auth::guard("api")->user();
```

Then you don't use any `auth` middleware. `$user` will be `null` if the user is a guest, otherwise it should be set.

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to do that in every function and check if user exists

Comment: I feel like this is the cleanest method. The accepted answer modifies the route middleware based on incoming data... seems hacky.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I used was to create a new middleware for auth:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
{

    try
    {
        $this->authenticate($request, $guards);
    }
    catch(AuthenticationException $ex)
    {

    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

and in at the BOTTOM of my route I did:

```
Route::middleware('auth_optional:api')->group(function () {
    Route::get('services', [ServiceController::class,'index']);
});
```

This way if Auth was needed ,it would assign the correct user to request, otherwise it would proceed as guest. I did need to do a $request->user() === null to make sure the user is guest

Answer (score 0):

I would like to use additional routes both authenticated and non-authenticated users,
But regarding the topic I add one simple way :

On the `__constructor` function of the Controller add those lines :

```
$authorizationHeader = \request()->header('Authorization');
        if(isset($authorizationHeader)) {
            $this->middleware('auth:api');
        }
```

But I don't concentrate this way as best practice, this brokes Single Responsibility Principle.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Laravel Passport then this way can be more cleaner.

In controller you can directly get user by

```
$user = $request->user('api');
```

This will get you the authenticated user and if bearer token is invalid then it will not throw 'unauthenticated' error but result in null user.

Reference: [How to authenticate user without auth:api middleware in laravel 5.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42481573/how-to-authenticate-user-without-authapi-middleware-in-laravel-5-3)

Answer (score 0):

```
$middlewares = \Request::header('Authorization') ? ['jwt.verify', 'auth:api'] : [];

Route::middleware($middlewares)->group(function () {
    Route::get('/demo/{id}','App\Http\Controllers\Api\DemoController@demo');
});
```

based on @Roham Shojaei answer. looks pretty much readable.